# HttpURLConnection crashes application

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I want to receive and send data with a web server but the code does not work
What do I do for this code to work?

Note this code inside onCreate

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://myweb.com/");
    HttpURLConnection   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStream Stream = connection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(Stream);
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(reader);
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    String str ="";

    while ((str = b.readLine())!=null)  {
        s.append(str);

    }
    String data = s.toString();
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text);
    myText.setText(data);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate by `does not work`. Are you getting an error? No Server response? Getting unexpected response code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do network-related tasks on a separate thread in Android. Also, check that you have the `INTERNET` permission set.

If you want to then update the UI from another thread, you have to use

```
runOnUiThread (new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        //update ui in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Already the error went but there was no result from the server
Please, I want to talk to you on Facebook

Comment: Sorry I don't have a Facebook account. You can start a chat on StackOverflow with me

Answer (score 0):

All your code runs in Main thread which should be always used for setting up the UI and to listen for UI events such as on click listeners.

Network calls are not allowed on this thread as they might take long time. Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) API of android which is designed for running code in separate thread.

Create a class like one below for all GET request tasks.

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    private String TAG = "InDownloadTask";
    private DownloadCallback callback;
    private String data;

    public DownloadTask(DownloadCallback cb){
        callback = cb;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer result = 0;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                data = response.toString();
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
        callback.onFinishDownload(data, integer);
    }

}
```

Create a callback interface that we use for the above class.

```
public interface DownloadCallback {
    public void onFinishDownload(String data, Integer result);
}
```

Now from your activity onCreate

```
String url = "http://myweb.com/";
new DownloadTask(new DownloadCallback() {
    public void onFinishDownload(String data, Integer result) {
        if(result == 1)
            myText.setText(data);
        else 
            myText.setText("Error");
    }
}).execute(url);
```

If you have many network related operations, use a Network library such as [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) which will take care of this.